# Replace items from a list with items with matching constructors in another list

Tags: haskell

To simplify the problem I'm facing, assume this data type:

```
data Item = X Int | Y Char deriving (Eq, Show..)
```

and two lists

```
let a = [X 1, Y 'g']
let b = [X 2]
```

I need to replace all items in `a` with the first (or any) item in `b` with the same constructor. So the result would be: `[X 2, Y 'g']`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing ideas from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500710/grouping-data-types-by-constructor-in-haskell/26501762#26501762) by Petr Pudlák you could try:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (nubBy, find)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

data Item = X Int | Y Char
  deriving (Eq, Show, Typeable, Data)

a = [X 1, Y 'g']
b = [X 2]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ map replace a
  where b' = nubBy (on (==) toConstr) b -- remove duplicates
        replace x = fromMaybe x $ find (on (==) toConstr x) b'
```

You can also skip removing the duplicates in b and use b instead of b' in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a function to replace the items:

```
specialReplace :: Item -> Item -> Item
specialReplace (X x1) (X x2) = (X x1)
specialReplace (Y y1) (Y y2) = (Y y1)
specialReplace _ a = a
```

and then:

```
foldr (\el list -> map (specialReplace el) list) a b
```

will run trough your `a` list and apply the correlated substitutions in `b` accordingly. Of course if more `X`s or `Y`s are introduced in the `b` list, then last one will be used at the end.

[<kbd>Your live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa76d39b4cce0a75)[<kbd>Another live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bb4f2deb86acd2f)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need a way to determine what constructor has been used:

```
isX :: Item -> Bool
isX (X _) = True
isX _ = False

-- If you have more than 2 constructors you'll have to write them all like isX
isY :: Item -> Bool
isY = not . isX
```

And a method to get the first value of each kind of constructor

```
import Data.Maybe

firstX :: [Item] -> Maybe Item
firstX = listToMaybe . filter isX

firstY :: [Item] -> Maybe Item
firstY = listToMaybe . filter isY
```

Then a way to replace items

```
replaceItem :: Item -> Maybe Item -> Item
replaceItem = fromMaybe

replaceItems :: [Item] -> Maybe Item -> Maybe Item -> [Item]
replaceItems [] _ _ = []
replaceItems (item:items) x y =
    (if isX item
        then replaceItem item x
        else replaceItem item y) : replaceItems items x y
```

But since this is just a map:

```
replaceXY :: Item -> Maybe Item -> Maybe Item -> [Item]
replaceXY item x y =
    if isX item
        then replaceItem item x
        else replaceItem item y

replaceItems items x y = map (\item -> replaceXY item x y) items
```

And finally you just have to combine this with `firstX` and `firstY`:

```
replaceFrom :: [Item] -> [Item] -> [Item]
replaceFrom a b =
    let x = firstX b
        y = firstY b
    in replaceXY a x y
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given `Item` and a list to be replaced, consider,

```
replace' :: Item -> [Item] -> [Item]
replace' _ [] = []
replace' (X i) ((X j):xs) = (X i) : replace' (X i) xs
replace' (Y i) ((Y j):xs) = (Y i) : replace' (Y i) xs
replace' r (x:xs) = x : replace' r xs
```

in which each pattern related to each type in `Item`. In this approach the latest occurrence of each type will be kept in the replaced list.